# Update achievements from a banned console

Tags: xbox-360, achievements

I have a banned Xbox 360 from two or three years. And I would like to buy a new one but all my achievements aren't updated. Is there some method or advice for updating it?

Comment: can you copy your gamertag to a usb stick, then to the new console? it may be your gamertag/xbl account was banned along with your console though?

Comment: I already have tried that but with a friend butHis console says that my profile is corrupt, but when I put it again on my console worked again.

Comment: why was your console banned? if you've hacked it, it may be that it's modifying the profile in ways that make it invalid?

Comment: I assume you mean 'achievements' instead of 'archivements'?

Comment: @Robotnik You're right (How embarrassing)

Comment: @TZHX My console was banned because it was modified (A friend flash it) and I played some asian games in my console which didn't exists in my region (Europe). I think that the profile is not banned because I can log in on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Xbox 360 profiles can be migrated by saving the profile to either a hard drive or USB stick and loading it on the new console. Assuming your profile wasn't also banned, the following steps describe how:

1. Plug a USB flash drive or an Xbox 360 Memory Unit (original Xbox 360
   console only) into your console.
2. Go to Settings and then select Storage.
3. Select All Devices.
4. Select Gamer Profiles, and then select your gamer profile
5. Select Move.
6. Select the USB Storage Device or Memory Unit that you want to move your profile to.
7. Remove the USB flash drive or memory unit from your console and take it to another console.

Comment: I already have tried that but it didn't work. As far as I know my profile is it not banned only the console.

Comment: @JCalcines In what way did it not work?

Comment: I moved my profile to other console and I tried to log in but the other console told me that my profile was corrupt. However when I tried to log in with it on my own console I worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend has the same model console as you (Original or S/E models), remove the hard drive (unless it's the 4GB internal flash memory) and attach it to your friend's console. Only the system is banned, not your HDD. HOWEVER, If your hard drive is formatted/modified in such a way that violates the Terms of Use, don't risk banning your friend's console too.

Here's how to add/remove the HDD: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/add-remove-hard-drive

Comment: This could work but unfortunately, I don't have any friend with the same model.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the hard drive off or out and place it in another xbox and it will work fine.